# TableView включение горизонтального скролла

Tags: java, javafx

В моей таблице будет множество колонок(32) и соответственно без прокрутки это будет несмотрибельно. Я знаю, что при заполнении таблицы строками, вертикальный скролл появится автоматически, и как я вычитал, что если таблица создана с параметром `ColumnResizePolicy` как `UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE` (это через Scene Building) то горизонтальный скролл появляется автоматически (если элементы столбцов не помещаются в таблице), но увы у меня это не так. Так же в классе контроллере я пробовал создать `ScrollPane`, положить туда таблицу и придать значение `setVvalue`, но это так же не помогло. Помогите разрешить этот вопрос пожалуйста.
Так я экспериментировал в контроллере:

```
@FXML
private TableView<String> dateTable;

@FXML
void initialize() {
    ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(dateTable);
    sp.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);
}
```

Comment: Для `ScrollPane` включение горизонтального скролла производится так: `functionChoosePane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.AS_NEEDED);`, вместо `AS_NEEDED` можно поставить `NEVER` или `ALWAYS`.

Comment: functionChoosePane в данном случае - это имя экземпляра ScrollPane? Я уточняю, т.к. у меня пока это не заработала, я скорректирую код в вопросе, как я написал

Comment: Из своей программы скопировал и забыл поменять имя)

Comment: @ИмяФамилия а как у Вас написано приложение (SB или руками через класс обычный)? просто дело в том, если я просо указываю это свойство, то не работает скролл

Comment: Обычный класс. Не знаю, как вам в fxml помочь.

Comment: @ИмяФамилия просто обычные свойства к элементам построенным в FXML файле применяются, а это не хочет, очень странно, но скорее всего я что-то не вижу, в любом случае спасибо, буду разбираться

Comment: судя по приведенному коду, вы создаете экземпляр ScrollPane, но на макете сцены именно его нет.

Comment: @Maxim а можно чутка поподробнее? Объясню как вижу это я. Файлом fxml я создаю полностью окно, где находится моя таблица, уже в контроллере я создаю экземпляр скролла, кидаю туда таблицу и присваиваю некие свойства, т.е. есть отображение(fxml) есть контроллер отвечающий за действия, где я создаю скролл

Comment: Ваш скрол не является дочерним элементом никакой ноды отображаемого окна. Это просто java class у которого вызван конструктор и метод, после чего он не используется и уничтожается gc.